# Autocomplete content after a pipe using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an input box or text area where users enter content like:

```
what is the best restaurant in Boston|City Massachusetts|State
```

When a user types the `|` symbol, I want a box to pop up as their typing with suggested labels to autocomplete. As the user types, the word `Ci`, `City` will pop up and they can arrow down or over, select `City` and hit enter, completing the text and adding a space for the next word.

I suspect this is similar to how one might autocomplete email addresses or mentions, but those plugins have pretty strong limitations for spacing and inputs.

Anyone have any ideas of plugins or code that would enable this?

Comment: Why not just use three separate inputs with normal auto complete controls? That seems far more intuitive for users, and quicker to build

Answer (score 0):

Check this Autocomplete With Tags plugin

http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-tags.html

This may be suitable for you. You need to customize to show the pipe symbol after each keyword.

Hope it helps.